# Is goto supported in PHP 5.2.8?

Tags: php

Is [`goto`](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.goto.php) supported in PHP 5.2.8?

Comment: Have you tried using it? Typing `goto` is simpler than typing a question here ;)

Comment: m trying one simple example like <?php

 goto a;
 echo 'welcome';
 
 a:
 echo 'agile';
?>
bt it gives Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /opt/lampp/htdocs/amol-test/goto.php on line 3

Comment: Why was this question closed? Asking if PHP 5.2.8 supports the `goto` operator is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @Asaph: For me it was a knee-jerk reaction to the poor quality of the question, from a poor quality user, and it's a simple reference question that could have easily been looked up. I agree that it is valid, but I didn't want to encourage the way it was asked. Read the users other questions: they're all phrased the same way. Editing and voting to reopen on technical grounds only.

Comment: i dont have php compiler now, and i want to know the answer as well. and the documentation is not clear.

Comment: The documentation is exceedingly clear, @ElliotYap.

Answer (score 12):

No. The goto operator is not available in php 5.2.8. According to the [goto documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php):

> Note:
>
> The goto operator is available as of PHP 5.3.